# WIX - Getting source files from an environment variable path

Tags: wix

I'am new to WIX, trying to create an msi with feature tree.

1. The installer should install all the assemblies in folder `C:\ProgramFile\MyDir\MyApp`.
2. Reading path from an environment variable called `MyFolder`.

   ```
   <WixVariable Id ="MyFolder" Value="[%MyFolder]"/>
   ```
3. Below is the code from where the assemblies are read.

   ```
   <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="ProgramFilesFolder">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder.MyDIR" Name="MyDIR">
   <Directory Id="PROGRAMFILESFOLDER.MyDIR.MyApp" Name="MyApp">

   <Component Id="Component.aaa.dll" Guid="guid1">
     <File Id="aaa.dll" Source="..\..\OutPut\aaa.dll" />
   </Component>
   ```
4. Now I would like to get the assemblies from the folder `MyFolder` which is an environment variable and append it to my Source

   ```
   <Directory Id="MyFolder" Name="MyFolder" SourceName="MyFolder">
     <Component Id="Component.bbb.exe" Guid="guid2">
       <File Id="bbb.exe" Name="bbb.exe" Vital="yes" Source=MyFolder + bbb.exe />
     </Component>
   </Directory>
   ```

I receive a compilation error saying it is unable to find bbb.exe.

Please let me know on where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Preprocessor](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/preprocessor.htm) documentation. I think you can simply do this to get bbb.exe from a path defined in an environment variable:

```
<File Id="bbb.exe" Name="bbb.exe" Vital="yes" Source="$(env.MyFolder)bbb.exe" />
```

Comment: I think this is the correct way to do it. I'm going to try to delete my answer, because it doesn't work.